# access data context from keypress event

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im  catching the keys pressed in a meteor app at the $("body") level. But inside the keypress callback I want to have access to the data context but I don't know how to get to it.

```
  Template.somename.rendered = function() {          
    $("body").keypress(function(e) {     
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();

      // change stuff on the data context
```

From the template i'm accessing the data context as {{this.data}}.

Any ideas on how to go about it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Template.somename.rendered = function() {
  var self = this;
  $("body").keypress(function(e) {
    console.log(self.data);
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
};
```

Depending on what you are doing, you may be better off modifying some session data in your `keypress` callback instead of directly manipulating the template, but it's hard to say without knowing more.

Comment: Ah, I see the trick there. you save the data context when the rendered is called. Even so it's not working. I'm using underscore to extend the this.data and maybe its losing the reactivity... I can try to put this extended part in a session and after access it from an helper...

Comment: Done! I moved the extended part to a session and it worked. Usually the errors are caused because of the mentality that pushes me to manipulate the DOM. This was one of those cases.

Comment: Great. I'm glad you got it working. I find that in general, unless you have a really complex ui component, the more you do with sessions or other reactive variables the better off you are. Lots of direct DOM manipulation is often a sign you are doing something wrong.